# twitterBootstrap is not recognized in play framework 2.4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play framework 2.4. I tried to use bootstrap as guided at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers.

In my template, I used the import statement:

```
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
```

But I got a compilation error:

```
object twitterBootstrap is not a member of package views.html.helper
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it has beed removed as mentioned here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/Migration23

```
The in-built Twitter Bootstrap field constructor has been deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of Play.

There are a few reasons for this, one is that we have found that Bootstrap changes too drastically between versions and too frequently, such that any in-built support provided by Play quickly becomes stale and incompatible with the current Bootstrap version.
```

For those who use play 2.4