# object twitterBootstrap is not a member of package views.html.helper

Tags: scala, playframework

Read from stdout: D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest5\app\views\products\editProduct.scala.html:11: object twitterBootstrap is not a member of package views.html.helper
D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest5\app\views\products\editProduct.scala.html:11: object twitterBootstrap is not a member of package views.html.helper
Read from stdout:

### @Messages("products.form")

### @Messages("products.form")

Read from stdout: ^
     ^

Comment: This is Spamming, not asking a question! :|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitterBootstrap is not recognized in play framework 2.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742644/twitterbootstrap-is-not-recognized-in-play-framework-2-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/Migration23#Twitter-Bootstrap:

> The in-built Twitter Bootstrap field constructor has been deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of Play.
>
> There are a few reasons for this, one is that we have found that Bootstrap changes too drastically between versions and too frequently, such that any in-built support provided by Play quickly becomes stale and incompatible with the current Bootstrap version.